# How to preserve imports from evaluate to make it available for following evaluate calls

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I have a xml file, containing groovy script text as follows

```
<agent>
 <request id=1>
  <snippet>
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;

   pageText = "My Page Text";
  </sniipet>
 </request>
 <request id=2>
  <snippet>

   Pattern matchlinkPat=Pattern.compile("callEvent",Pattern.MULTILINE);
   Matcher match = matchlinkPat.matcher(pageText);

  </sniipet>
 </request>
</agent>
```

I am evaluating string text in `<snippet>` tag from my Java class as follows

```
//Inside my Java Class
Binding binding = new Binding();
GroovyShell groovyshell = new GroovyShell(binding);

//Iterate each snippet tag and evaluate the script code
public Object evaluate(String code) {
    return groovyshell.evaluate(code);
}
```

The first snippet gets evaluated, but the second snippet fails to evaluate.

**If I redeclare the imports in second snippet, it gets evaluated without any error.**

Is there any way in which I can make my imports available to following snippet text?

Comment: in each compilation unit you have to provide your imports. So, you have the only option to concatenate both snippets together and compile the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible, because [`GroovyShell.evaluate(String script)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.10/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html#evaluate-java.lang.String-) creates a Groovy script class using code you pass a String and then it runs it.

```
/**
 * Evaluates some script against the current Binding and returns the result
 *
 * @param codeSource
 * @throws CompilationFailedException
 */
public Object evaluate(GroovyCodeSource codeSource) throws CompilationFailedException {
    Script script = parse(codeSource);
    return script.run();
}
```

*Source: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.java#L590*

Each script runs in isolation, so Groovy shell does not record what the previous evaluation did - each one starts as a brand new script with bindings you pass a constructor parameter to `GroovyShell` class constructor. That's why your imports are never seen in second snippet. And basically second snippet without explicit imports is useless - Groovy shell behaves in this case correctly.

#### Groovy script bindings

You have asked in comments why `pageText` from first snippet is visible in the second one. It happens because Groovy script uses [bindings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) mechanism to store and retrieve variables. Groovy's `Script` class overrides `getProperty(String property)` and `setProperty(String property, Object value)` methods in following way:

```
public Object getProperty(String property) {
    try {
        return binding.getVariable(property);
    } catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
        return super.getProperty(property);
    }
}

public void setProperty(String property, Object newValue) {
    if ("binding".equals(property))
        setBinding((Binding) newValue);
    else if("metaClass".equals(property))
        setMetaClass((MetaClass)newValue);
    else
        binding.setVariable(property, newValue);
}
```

*Source: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/groovy/groovy/lang/Script.java#L54*

As you can see any time you try to access variable in a Groovy script or you try to assign a value to a variable in a script, it retrieves from and stores this information in `bindings` object (you can think about `bindings` object as a `Map<String, Object>`). And because you evaluate both snippets using same `GroovyShell` instance, both scripts are using the same `bindings` object. That's why `pageText` from the first snippet gets stored in `bindings` object and when you use this variable in second snippet it gets resolved from `bindings` with no problem.

Comment: If a different is created everytime, how am I NOT getting an error for accessing the `pageText` variable in second snippet? `pageText` should be unknown for second snippet, right? But If I `println(pageText)` in second snippet the value from first snippet gets printed.

Comment: @Nishant123 `pageText` is visible for second snippet, because Groovy script stores and retrieves all variables from `bindings` object you passed to `GroovyShell` constructor. I have updated my answer with more detailed explanation on how bindings are being used in Groovy script.

Comment: Thanks!!. That helped